# A custom Textbox - WPF and Xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I want to make a custom `TextBox` using XAML and a custom class with an additional property to TextBox called `PosType`.  `PosType` will be rendered inside the red triangle in the side.

The `TextBox` should be an ordinary textbox with enough margin from left to not intercept the other text.
Here is the Image showing the desired look of the textbox.

[image: The desired text box]

**The Control class :**

```
public class PosTextBox : TextBox
{
    public string PosType { get; set; }
}
```

**The style I wrote : (quite similar approach to what I want except here I used border and other parts may not be accurate. **

```
xmlns:Pro="clr-namespace:Prox.XamlControls">

<!-- Custom TextBox  -->
<Style x:Key="c1PosTextBox" TargetType="{x:Type Pro:PosTextBox}" >
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Pro:PosTextBox}">

                <Grid>
                    <Border>
                        <Border>
                            <TextBlock Text ="{TemplateBinding Path= Pro:PosType}"></TextBlock>
                            <!--<TextBlock Text ="{TemplateBinding ElementName=Pro:PosTextBox, Path= Pro:PosType}"></TextBlock>-->
                        </Border>
                    </Border>
                    <Border Margin="5,10,5,10">
                        <ContentPresenter  Name="Content" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" TextBlock.Foreground="White"></ContentPresenter>
                    </Border>
                </Grid>

            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

How to create this custom textbox and achieve the desired look?

**Edit:**
Please guide me to fix the minor issues based on the same approach I mentioned above.

Comment: I think [Adorners](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743737.aspx) is what you are looking for

Comment: I'm quite sure it can be done in both ways, I like to hear answers on both of the approaches if anyone liked to share. thanks mentioning this

Comment: Implementing this using adorners and attached behaviors can bring you more flexibility than using custom type (like `PosTextBox`) for every UI feature.

Comment: After playing a bit with the suggested approaches, I stayed with mine on this case, Based on what I need I want exact the same approach as I provided in my question, If anybody knows how can I fix the code I provided to do job please help me this way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do that using [Adorners](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743737.aspx)

Adorners are rendered in a different layer called `AdornerLayer` on top of the `UIElement`, Which can get you the desired affect.

```
public class PosTypeAdorner : Adorner
{
     private string _posText;

     // Be sure to call the base class constructor. 
     public PosTypeAdorner (UIElement adornedElement, string posText) : base(adornedElement) 
     { 
           _posText = posText;
     }

     // A common way to implement an adorner's rendering behavior is to override the OnRender 
     // method, which is called by the layout system as part of a rendering pass. 
     protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext drawingContext)
     {
          // Draw the red triangle with it's text using the drawingContext here
     }
 }
```

Assuming you want the text of the `PosType` to be bindable, you should make it as a `Dependency property`. 
Use `OnApplyTemplate` to attach the adorner to your text box

```
public class PosTextBox : TextBox
{
    public PosTextBox()
    {
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty PosTypeProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("PosType", typeof (string), typeof (PosTextBox), new PropertyMetadata(default(string)));

    public string PosType
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(PosTypeProperty); }
        set { SetValue(PosTypeProperty, value); }
    }

    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();

        var layer = AdornerLayer.GetAdornerLayer(this);
        var posAdorner = new PosTypeAdorner(this, PosType);

        layer.Add(posAdorner);
    }
}
```

For more information, you can check out this links:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/54472/Defining-WPF-Adorners-in-XAML

http://www.nbdtech.com/Blog/archive/2010/06/21/wpf-adorners-part-1-ndash-what-are-adorners.aspx

http://www.nbdtech.com/Blog/archive/2010/06/28/wpf-adorners-part-2-ndash-placing-any-control-on-the.aspx

Good luck

Comment: thanks for the info, +1, but it doesn't contain the adorner definition bound to the custom control which helping me achieving this, could you extend your answer.

Comment: I try to play around these subjects, and wait a while, If I didn't get any better answer will mark it, thanks for extending it and giving your solution.

Comment: @Sypress extended my answer. basically all is left to do is draw the rectangle. I've never actually implemented my own adorner only used existing one so I can't post you the code of how to do that, but it should be fairly easy and has great documentation on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743737.aspx#implement_custom_Adorner). Good luck :)

Comment: I'm sure you did the most major implementation of it, my doubts about your code is : It isn't based on Xaml which I was thinking of it, yes, a bit I should play to get the desired triangle placed in the correct location. The last doubt is adapting it with prism?! 2 Questions on this? 1. I rarely used adorners, how can I be sure of the place it will be rendered? any margins or setting about pixels? 2. Is the string "PosType" placed in the location of "XYZ" in your adorner implementation or not? thanks.

Comment: @Sypress In my implementation `PosText` represents the "XYZ" string. as I understood your question, you wanted it to be changable, didn't you? About adapting it to `Prism`, not quite sure what you mean .. this is a custom `UIElement`. you can place it in any view you would like and bind the `PosType` or any other properties that you'll decide to implement to your `ViewModel` just as you would on any other control. It shouldn't affect your MVVM design at all. same thing for your `Adorner`

Comment: @Sypress as for the pixels of the adorner, the `DrawingContext` parameter in the `OnRender` method has a lot of `DrawXXX` method which you can use. One that perhaps you'll find most useful for you case is `DrawText` and `DrawLine` which takes a `Point` as a parameter to define it's drawing points. you can make this hard coded or make in bindable like the `PosText` example. Hope this helps :)

Comment: Your answer should be working as I said, and it's a good candidate to be a solution, but still I'm eager to find out a correct similar solution to what I provided, some pieces of my code are based on Xaml gathered in one place. I'll play with your code more. probably mark it as the answer in the next 12 hours ;)

Comment: @Sypress Sounds good :) Don't forget that the `Adorner` takes the `TextBox` as parameter in it's constructor and you can access it by `this.AdornedElement` and draw your triangle accordingly to it's height/width/any other property. Look, I agree that getting dirty with all the `Drawing` shindig can be quite nasty, but it has worked quite well for us, and proven to be a really good solution. it's true power revieled it self when we rewrote our xaml's to get a new look-and-feel and didn't have to rewrite this part since we implemented it with adorners. Just something to think about :P

Comment: nice hints, yes sometimes this approach wins and some times the other, if I be right. :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38112/discussion-between-sypress-and-omribitan)